# Table 'wp_signups' doesn't exist

Tags: buddypress

I'm seeing thousands of this PHP error in NewRelic. That table does not exist in the DB but it seems like Buddypress is looking for it.

Any ideas on why it doesn't exist, or how to get BP to create it?

Comment: Single or Multisite setup?

Comment: Single site, strangely. I read that wp_signups is only for Multisite.

Comment: Have you had a Multisite setup before and switched to single site?

Comment: @kaiser - Yes I believe I did experiment with it a while back

Comment: Please ask further details on the BuddyPress support forums. It's off topic on this site. Still I hope we could help with pin pointing the actual problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should create it. you can find the schema in /wp-admin/includes/schema.php file. While it is used by core only in network mode, BP always uses it to track registration requests.

Comment: Are you sure I should do this instead of figuring out why it's trying to use a table that's only used for multisite?

Comment: I would recommend against this one from what I could read in BuddyPress support forums and install instructions.

Comment: I had the non pleasure of doing some work relating to BP sign-ups last week therefor I am pretty sure in what I say. In any case this is a core wordpress table, the question is not why BP tries to write to it but why doesn't it exist.